# GWT addon doesn't install on Spring Roo on STS - Command 'web gwt setup' not found

Tags: java, spring, gwt, spring-roo, spring-tool-suite

I'm using last version of STS and have a Spring Roo project.

Each time I try to install GWT addon to the project, then setup the project to use GWT, I get an error message stating that the GWT isn't installed.

```
roo> web gwt setup
Command 'web gwt setup' not found (for assistance press CTRL+SPACE or type "hint" then hit ENTER)
Located add-on that may offer this command
1 found, sorted by rank; T = trusted developer; R = Roo 1.3 compatible
ID T R DESCRIPTION -------------------------------------------------------------
01 Y Y 1.2.5.RELEASE Support for UI scaffolding using Google Web Toolkit.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[HINT] use 'addon info id --searchResultId ..' to see details about a search result
[HINT] use 'addon install id --searchResultId ..' to install a specific search result, or
[HINT] use 'addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName TAB' to install a specific add-on version
roo> addon install id --searchResultId 01
roo> Target resource(s):
-------------------
   Spring Roo - Addon - Google Web Toolkit (1.2.5.RELEASE)

Deploying...
done.

roo> 
roo> web  gwt setup
Command 'web gwt setup' not found (for assistance press CTRL+SPACE or type "hint" then hit ENTER)
```